# div visibility, opacity issue in android ( google nexus 4) webview

Tags: android, webview, nexus-4

I am making a div invisible by setting `div.style.visibility="hidden"`; which perfectly works in samsung, sony phones. Also perfectly works for desktop browsers, chrome mozilla. (And it should be.. )

But sometimes, it is not working in google nexus 4 (android 4.3). Tested in multiple nexus 4 device.

observations :

1. I have multiple dialogs, which navigates between one another. In this process, I hide the previous dialog and make the next dialog visible. This works perfectly fine until I open a heavy dialog, which has 100 divs with multiple images. Now, when I try to go back to a previous dialog, div visibility and opacity stop working. All dialogs remain visible in the background. style.opacity = 0 also doesn't work. visibility and opacity works perfectly fine, doesn't matter how many time I switch between dialogs, until I create that heavy dialog.
2. when a div is visible in the background, which should not be visible at all, and I lock and unlock the phone, this problem gets resolved. Everything starts working smoothly. Also, if I wait for sometime, everything falls back in place. Starts working perfectly again.

Tried couple of things :

```
1. webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE/HARDWARE, null);
2. webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH/LOW);
```

1. I will make that div small (with less inner divs) and try again tomorrow.
2. I will test in nexus 7 tab and other devices if possible.
3. I will test in nexus web browser.

For the time being, if anyone has any suggestion, please let me know

Comment: try `display:none`, it may screw up your layout though.

Comment: thanks, I will try it. Want to make it working by any means. The code is pretty simple and expected to work seamlessly on any platform.

Comment: `display:none` also doesn't have any impact. looks like a ghost image which persists on the screen. Tested with a smaller div(with less inner divs), and the problem doesn't occur. looks like a performance bug, when there is a heavy div, webview tries to keep the already rendered images.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. Not sure how to solve your issue but good luck.

Comment: @Sanmoy - do you have any solution ?